# How do I get rid of a fragment that is no longer being used

Tags: android-fragments

I am new to Android app programming and fragments.

I am transitioning between two fragments in my app with the use of two buttons. I noticed that hitting frgbutton1 and frgbutton2 (transitioning back and forth) creates a problem.

My first fragment is being overlapped by an exact copy of the first fragment.
My question is how do I destroy or remove the first fragment so that there is no overlapping copy later.

```
public void selectFrag(View view) {
    Fragment fr1 = null;
    Fragment fr2 = null;
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.frgbutton1)) {
        fr1 = new Fragment01();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fr1);

    }else if (view == findViewById(R.id.frgbutton2)) {
        fr2 = new Fragment02();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fr2);

    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void selectFrag(View view) {
    Fragment fr1 = null;
    Fragment fr2 = null;
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    if (view.getId()== R.id.frgbutton2) {
        fr1 = new Fragment01();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fr1);

    }else if (view.getId() == R.id.frgbutton1) {
        fr2 = new Fragment02();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fr2);

    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```